# Не получается импортировать модуль из Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, typescript

В исходном файле Bootstrap указаны экспорты:

```
  exports.Carousel = Carousel;
  exports.Collapse = Collapse;
  exports.Dropdown = Dropdown;
```

У себя в проекте пытаюсь сделать импорт:

`import { Dropdown as dropdown } from 'bootstrap'`

И получаю ошибку о том, что модуль `bootstrap` не экспортирует `Dropdown`. При этом, такой вариант импорта ошибок не выводит, но при попытке использования выводит ошибку:

```
import Dropdown from 'bootstrap'
$('#prefered-airline-dropdown').Dropdown({
    flip: false,
})
```

> Property 'Dropdown' does not exist on type 'JQuery'. Did you mean 'dropdown'?

Answer (score 0):

`Dropdown` - это название класса реализующее поведение.
[Документация](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/) говорит что нужно вызывать его так.

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

так что в своем проекте вызываете `dist/bootstrap.min.js` и работаете как указано в документации.